# No sound after suspend on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, suspend, pulseaudio

After recently upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 from 16.03 (and fixing most of the problems caused by that) I still have one persistent problem that won't go away.

After a "suspend" of the system the HDMI sound won't work anymore. I can get it to work again by starting "System Settings" or a reboot, but nothing else works. I tried adding the lines below to /etc/pulse/default.pa:

```
set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo
set-default-sink 0
```

But that didn't solve anything either. My system has a AMD A8-7600 CPU and I use the GPU of that for audio. It is device 0 according to "pacmd list-cards", device 1 is a generic intel audio device.

"System Settings" only shows 1 audio device. I really get the feeling that Ubuntu does not like AMD APUs given the huge amount of issues I had to find solutions for.

Any suggestions how to solve this audio issue?